# Are there review audits on this site?

Tags: discussion, reviewing, review-audits

There were past meta questions about review audits on this site, but are there any more audits now? I haven’t encountered one yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are currently no review audits on Puzzling. Puzzling did have review audits in the past but they were [switched off by Shog9](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5852/11110) after the community asked for it:

> Normally, audits aren't enabled on sites of this size; there just aren't enough reviews (or enough posts that meet the criteria for becoming audits) to justify it.
>
> I've disabled audits here until such a time as this site reaches a scale to both need and support them.